# Displaying a hundredth set of characters from a buffer in C

Tags: c, file, unix, io, buffer

Read TDT.txt (70 characters at a time) and display every hundredth set of
70 characters read.

So, I'm stuck on how to take the characters placed in this character buffer and print them to the screen where only every hundredth set is displayed. Here is my approach so far

```
int fileOpen = open("TDT.txt",2);
int fileClose = 0;
char read70[70];
int fileEnd = lseek(fileOpen,0,2); 
int test1 = lseek(fileOpen, 0,0);
for(i = 0; i < fileEnd; i++)
{
    fileRead = read(fileOpen,read70,70);
    count++;

    if(count == 100)
    {
       printf("%s",read70[i]);
       count = 0;
    }   
}
```

I'm not sure how to display the hundredth set of 70 characters. My above approach is just an attempt. I ended up getting a seg fault but im not sure why.

Comment: `read70[i]` is a single character. In essence it is a small integer. If it's encoded in [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (very likely) dividing it by `100` will result in `0` or `1` (since you use integer division). Then you make it worse by using the wrong [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format to display the value leading to *undefined behavior*. *And* you close the file in the loop, causing the `read` call in the next iteration to fail.

Comment: As for the assignment, it might be that you should read the whole file (70 character at a time) and display every hundredth character in the file. So you would display character number 100, 200, 300 etc.

Comment: Ah so read in 70 characters from the at a time and after the count is over a hundred then check if the index is increments of 100?

Comment: What confused me is when it says every hundredth set of characters. I wasn't sure how to interpret this

Comment: @LogNIsGood It means that you should skip 99 sets, print set 100, skip another 99 sets, print set 200, skip... and so on.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck, I added a counter after my fileRead which runs until 100 is reached then prints the character. I reset the counter back to 0 to start over until it reaches 100 again.

Comment: Also is it wise to use that  lseek to get the end of file size for my loop? Is there a better way?

Comment: It is better to just read in a loop until the return value is less than 70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it is meant that every 100th bucket, each comprising 70 characters, shall be printed out. See the code below, which does exactly this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {

    char buffer[71]; // 70 + 1 just for the sake of using printf later on...
    buffer[70] = '\0';

    int myFile = open("TDT.txt",O_RDONLY);
    if (myFile < 0)
        return 1;

    size_t charRead = 0;
    int nrOfSets=0;
    charRead = read(myFile, &buffer, 70);
    while (charRead == 70) {
        nrOfSets++;
        if (nrOfSets % 100 == 0)  // every 100th set read in?
            printf("set: %s\n", buffer);
        charRead = read(myFile, &buffer, 70);
    }
    close (myFile);
}
```

Comment: I thought it was meaning every 100th character